# How to extract all attributes from a Azure table entity object ?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a code that extracts specific attributes from an Azure Table entity object :

```
def run(self):

    file_handle=partition_key +'_blob.csv'


    ts=TableService(account_name='dev',account_key='eNiDww==')

    i=0

    next_pk=None
    next_rk=None


    part_k="PartitionKey eq '%s'"%(partition_key)

    with open(file_handle, 'a') as fp:    
        while True:
            entities=ts.query_entities('Eventsdata', filter=part_k,select = 'what goes here',next_partition_key=next_pk,next_row_key=next_rk,top=1000)
            i+=1
            json_dict={}
            for ent in entities:


                if hasattr(ent,'Day'):
                    day=ent.Day:
                else:
                    day=None

                if hasattr(ent,'EventDetailsJSON'):
                    eventJson=ent.EventDetailsJSON:
                else:
                    eventJson=None


                 if hasattr(ent,EventSubType):
                    eventSubtype=ent.EventSubType:
                else:
                    eventSubtype=None


                print(day,eventJson)
            \\
            if hasattr(entities,'x_ms_continuation'):
                x_ms_continuation=getattr(entities,'x_ms_continuation')
                next_pk=x_ms_continuation['nextpartitionkey']
                next_rk=x_ms_continuation['nextrowkey']
            else:
                break;
```

I can specify as many fields as I want and extract them.

Is there a way to extract all the attributes without specifying specific fields? In the tableservice.query_entities function there is an optional handle for selecting fields but not sure if there is a command to select all the fields.

The reason being if more attributes get added in the future then this code would not capture them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all fields simply don't specify anything for 'select'.

Comment: yes, that is what I have been doing, but is there any way to extract attributes without doing 'entityobject.attributename' for every single attribute name? i.e. something that will dump all attributes inside an entity object

Comment: dump the attributes to what?

Comment: e.g. right now I do :

    file.write('{}|{}".format(day, eventJson)). I want to get all this data without specifying the two fields so that in the future if a 3rd or 4th field gets added I dont have to change the code and add the new fields to get that data.